# Grouping methods in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Is there any way I can group certain functions in a class? Sort of like creating a subclass.

For example, how can I do something like this?:

```
className::food::fruit('lemon');
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You can extend your class from other one. Class a extends b... then class b has access to a:s methods. Extend chains can be as deep as you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly separate functions within a single class into different reference paths based on the classname like this. The closest available thing would be to use Namespaces (available from PHP 5.3+) and create multiple classes within your namespace, each with their own set of functions. Example:

```
namespace className;

class food {

    static function fruit() {

    }

}
```

Would be called by

```
className\food::fruit('lemon');
```

*It does not make sense to call a namespace "className" - used only to match your example.*

Namespaces can have many levels of nesting as well if you need more group levels.

Note this is fundamentally different to your example as this will end up with multiple classes to achieve the function grouping as per your example, where I think you're looking for a similar solution but with only a single class - which is not possible.

Note this is different to the other answers showing inheritance - as they provide different grouping locations to define the functions but do not allow distinctly different ways to reference them on an existing object or statically from the class itself.

More information here: http://php.net/namespaces

**Note - I do think inheritance would be the right way to go based on your example code - namespaces do not sound like a good fit for the example given - however if you want "subclasses" as mentioned in your question, this might be closer to what you're looking for.**

**A combination of the two is likely going to give the best result (and is very common practice).**

Answer (score 0):

PHP supports inheritance, so you could write a fruit class and then another child class, lemon, that inherits fruit.

Answer (score 0):

See this example for using class extension and abstract classes.

```
// Abstract class can regisiter functions that MUST be implemented by extending 
// classes
abstract class Fruit {
    public function type();
}

// Lemon extends Fruit, so it must implement its own version of the type() method.
class Lemon extends Fruit {
    public function type() {
        return "Lemon";
    }
}

// Grape also extends Fruit, but this will create an error because it is not
// implementing the type() method in the abstract class Fruit
class Grape extends Fruit {
}


$lemon = new Lemon();
echo $lemon->type();

// This will give you an error because the Grape class did not implement the 
// type() as the Fruit class requires it to.
$grape = new Grape();
echo $grape->type();
```

The PHP documentation does a great job of explaining class extension.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php